# In PHP, why doesn't mysqli_num_rows return an integer for a query with 0 returned rows?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am having a strange issue with mysqli_num_rows. Searching for this issue, I've only found people having issues where NULL is returned no matter what. I also checked the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) for the function, and it says it returns an integer of the number of rows returned by the query. Whenever my query returns 1 row (it never should return more), it behaves as I expect. When the query returns 0 rows, I expect the function to return 0, but it returns NULL. Why doesn't it return 0?

I know that my database connection is good and my query works correctly, because when I look for a record that's in the database, I get an integer  back. I just can't figure out why this is returning NULL rather than 0.

```
function getArtistID($name) {
    global $conn; 
    $query = "SELECT artist_id FROM artist WHERE artist_name LIKE '${name}'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if ($result->num_rows) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $row['artist_id'];
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know? Given this code, the behavior whether it returns `0` or `null` should be the same. I have a feeling that `mysqli_query` is the one returning null, not `mysqli_num_rows`.

Comment: Don't use `global`. That's clear indicator of bad design if your code needs it.

Comment: @tkausl yes, that is true. But I'm curious why it doesn't return 0. The docs don't mention it returning NULL ever.

Comment: I _really_ believe you're misinterpreting some information. If it _really_ returns null, please show how you got to that conclusion exactly, including any code with `var_dump`s and the corresponding output.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski ok, I'll look in to avoiding it. Why is it bad design? I am doing this because I have a php file that establishes a connection to the database that I have used an include statement on, and when I tried it without global, it couldn't find the connection variable.

Comment: @tkausl I simply used an echo statement to display the results of calling this function. When it got a record, it returned 1, when it didn't it returned NULL. What am I misinterpreting?

Comment: People often say that using `global` is bad, because it makes it hard to write unit tests. You can't test a function in limited scope if it references global variables. It's awkward to create mock objects for globals. See https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.0/fixtures.html#global-state

Comment: Since PHP is bad design from the scratch, `global` does not make it much worse. When building based on a framework using multiple extension modules from different third party distributors, globals could introduce conflicts. In a fully self-written project it can make things easier to code. Professional code should neither use globals nor PHP. Gloabals in general are also considered as a security issue, however, in PHP we cannot prevent anything from being found and accessed. So globals only make it easier for malicious codes.

Comment: @blakeF. because it simply breaks code isolation. If your method, function needs something, pass it to it. Do not make it fetch that thing by itself. Unit tests will be painful (same with "new" operator vs. using dependency injection). I assume this is far ahead of you, so for now: ditch `global`, pass `$conn` as argument to `getArtistID()`. BTW: it should be `getArtistId()` not `getArtistID()` if you follow camel case.

Answer (score 4):

Here's some code that I used to reproduce a case where `num_rows` seems to be NULL:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$conn = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', null, 'test');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dual";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result === false) {
  print "Error: {$conn->error}\n";
}
$n = $result->num_rows;
echo "Dump the num_rows property: ";
var_dump($n);
```

Output:

```
Error: No tables used

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/bkarwin/Documents/SO/my.php on line 14
Dump the num_rows property: NULL
```

The notice is because it's invalid to access an object-oriented property of a variable that is not an object. This is a frequent source of confusion for PHP developers, and it's a byproduct of the fact that PHP is a loosely typed language, and functions like `query()` can return *either* a result object, or a boolean scalar.

The `query()` function actually returned a **false** as `$result` because of some error. In my code, I checked for this error, and you didn't.

When you run `mysqli::query()` or `mysqli::prepare()` or `mysqli_stmt::execute()`, you must check for error conditions **every time**.

Something about your query caused an error. It's up to you to check for the error and report it.

---

Update: I edited some text above to make the explanation better, but it might make some comments below seem out of place.

Comment: Ok, I will add the check. But when I run the query in phpmyadmin, I get no errors. I also, don't get any odd behavior when it returns rows. My table does have columns. I'm not really understanding your point here.

Comment: My query is just one example of a query that generates an error. I'm saying that your query probably generates some different error. The point is that you're not checking for errors.

Comment: I see. I guess my thought process was that checking if ($result->num-rows) was a sufficient check because it would be false if anything went wrong. But I see how this is better.

Comment: I guess you are also not calling `error_reporting()` to enable the notice you should get you call `$result->num_rows` when `$result` is the boolean value **false**. You can't request an object-oriented property from a variable unless it's an object. When the variable is a scalar, you should get a notice, when you configure the error reporting level correctly. That's shown in my code example.

Comment: In my example, when I try to set `$n = $results->num_rows;` the notice interrupts that assignment, and `$n` gets no value at all, that's why when I dump `$n` it is NULL, because it never got a value.

Comment: When you don't configure PHP to output notices, and you don't check for errors yourself, you get lots of confusing effects, because you have no idea when errors have occurred.

Comment: It should be required reading for PHP developers to study https://phptherightway.com/ and practice all the recommendations.

Comment: _" you must check for error conditions every time"_  you can configure MySQLi to throw exceptions so you don't have to do these checks. [How to get MySQLi error information in different environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-information-in-different-environments)

Comment: @Phil, Yes that's true, but given a newbie PHP developer who isn't even aware of `error_reporting()`, exception-handling is usually too advanced for them.

Comment: Who's talking about exception _"handling"_? Given the right error reporting, uncaught exceptions are hard to miss 

Comment: I know, but spewing excepts and stack traces doesn't make for a good user experience. The developer has to learn how to catch them and do something sensible like logging, recovery, retries, etc.

Comment: I'm in doubt too whether or not I should give the advice to throw exeptions to beginners. I expect they do not distinguish between development and productive system and will expose possible sensitive information to the public. On the other hand it is a real advantage on debugging.

Answer (score 1):

> I just can't figure out why this is returning NULL rather than 0.

We can only guess without seeing the log output; but, it is likely the return value is null because it raised an error instead.

You need to ensure that errors are handled when calling a function, before attempting to use the return value.